# Does having CDH oracle breaks El-Gamal signature scheme?

Tags: signature, diffie-hellman, group-theory, elgamal-signature

Having a oracle that solves Computational Diffie-Hellman problem which for given values $(g, g^a, g^b)$ outputs $g^{ab}$, is it possible to forge a signature in El-Gamal [(wiki)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ElGamal_signature_scheme) signature scheme?